# NGINX / Apache RewriteMap

Tags: apache, nginx, rewritemap

I would like to know how to translate Apache "RewriteMap" directives in NGINX.

I've found nothing in the NGINX online documentation

My current apache code is:

```
RewriteMap map-one txt:C:/map-one.txt
RewriteMap map-two txt:C:/map-two.txt

<Directory /> 
    Options All 
    AllowOverride All
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule /MYSITE/PRODUCT/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+),([0-9]+).aspx /$1/$2/${map-two:$3}/${map-one:$3} [R=301,L]
</Directory>
```

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 4):

Check [Nginx HTTP Map Module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMapModule)

```
map $uri $new {
  default               http://www.domain.com/home/;

  /aa                   http://aa.domain.com/;
  /bb                   http://bb.domain.com/;
  /john                 http://my.domain.com/users/john/;
}
```

Comment: Seems to have been some significant changes to the nGinx wiki.
[Nginx HTTP Map Module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html)